# About problem in complex integrals

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I solved this problem in complex integrals.

Is my answer a correct ?

Here $z$ is a complex value:

$$
C:|z-1|=1 \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{integral path}
$$

$$
\int_C\ \frac{2z^2-5z+1}{z-1}\ dz
$$

My answer

$$
z=1+e^{i\theta} \ \ \  \ \frac{dz}{d\theta}=ie^{i\theta}
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ \frac{-e^{i\theta}+2e^{2i\theta}-2}{e^{i\theta}} \cdot\ ie^{i\theta} d\theta
$$

$$
=\left[ -e^{i\theta}+ e^{2i\theta} -2i\theta \right]^{2\pi}_0=-4\pi i
$$

Comment: The approach seems correct.

Comment: The answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

If you are allowed to use the [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), then $$\int_{C} \frac{2 z^2 - 5x + 1}{z-1} dz = {2\pi i} \big( 2 z^2 - 5z + 1)_{z=1} = -4 \pi i,$$
showing that you did a great job.